# Find path of the PenDrive

Tags: android, usb-drive

I am beginner in android. 
How to find path of the PenDrive connected to android tablet programmatically at runtime. 
Because I need to store some files into the pendrive.

Comment: Yes. Android tablet with PenDrive.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to ask your device manufacturer. At the present time, the Android SDK has support for only one "external storage", and that will not be a "pen drive".

Comment: @CommonsWare you mean pen drive is not accessible from the android tablet? coz i can attach pendrive to my tablet and copy file and paste from the pendrive

Comment: @Droider: I mean exactly what I wrote. At the present time, the **Android SDK** has support for only one "external storage", and that will not be a "pen drive". Your **device** may have support for multiple forms of external storage, due to firmware changes made by the device manufacturer, but there is no documented and supported means to find out about those via the Android SDK.

Comment: @CommonsWare: so is it that i can use pendrive in my device but i will not be able to access it or even detect it through android.hardware.usb classes ?

Comment: @Droider: AFAICT, `android.hardware.usb` knows nothing of mount points and such. You might be able to detect that a pendrive exists, but you will not know the path on the filesystem, whether it is readable or writable, etc.

Comment: @CommonsWare: thanks i am struggling to get my pendrive detected since last 3 days but in vain, so now i atleast know it may get detected