# Find external USB storage device path programmatically?

Tags: android

I am new to android and I am doing some project planning.

I need to access / store some files to External storage device ( pendrive ). How to find external storage device path ( pendrive ).

Comment: Have you try this `String url = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();` ?

Comment: Check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5694933/find-an-external-sd-card-location)

Comment: Although the original title was bad, this is a question about USB storage devices, not the android ExternalStorage (sdcard or soldered-in flash)

Comment: @Chris I aggree this question title. But my problem is, I am using one android tablet and then i connected to the one external USB storage device ( Pendrive ). How to find out this external USB storage device path. Because i need to access some files from Pendrive. Sorry for bad english. Thanks for your idea..

Answer (score 1):

Someone else asked this recently [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11119016/1105376).

Basically, the SDK has support for only one "external storage", and that is an SD card, not a "pen drive".

Comment: Yup. Also, to my knowledge, no devices support USB storage devices out of the box. You can flash custom kernels which enable it on 4.0 devices, but as of yet I don't know of any devices which officially support it.

Answer (score 1):

USB device is recognized as `Mass Storage` device if:

```
usbInterface.getInterfaceClass() == UsbConstants.USB_CLASS_MASS_STORAGE
             || usbInterface.getInterfaceSubclass() == INTERFACE_SUBCLASS // int 6
             || usbInterface.getInterfaceProtocol() == INTERFACE_PROTOCOL // int 80
```

and

```
usbInterface.getEndpointCount() == 2
```

where one of endpoint must satisfy following:

```
endPoint direction == 0
endPoint type = UsbConstants.USB_ENDPOINT_XFER_BULK //int 2
```

Refer these links for further details:

- [Usb detect storage device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41890251/usbdevice-recognise-as-storage-device-and-find-path?noredirect=1&lq=1)
- [Usb device interface not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42088660/usbinterface-null-for-except-1-device?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Answer (score -2):

You will need an OTG cable and a rooted phone. Install Stick mount from play store. You can access pendrive

Comment: how exactly does this answer the question?

Answer (score -3):

This does give you the external Storage:

```
File root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
```

> Get a top-level public external storage directory for placing files of
>   a particular type. This is where the user will typically place and
>   manage their own files, so you should be careful about what you put
>   here to ensure you don't erase their files or get in the way of their
>   own organization.

See docs: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(java.lang.String)

Comment: Not relevant.  The original title was bad, but this is a question about USB storage devices, not the android ExternalStorage (sdcard or soldered-in flash)